# Compile the C-file in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, compilation, wolfram-mathematica, mex

#### Description

I got a *Mathematica* Symbolic Toolbox for MATLAB--Version 2.0 [here](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5344/)

Then I using the documentation it cotained to compile in MATLAB enviroment

#### Installation steps:

> - 1)Go to your *Mathematica* directory and locate the file `mathlink.h` in 
>     E:\math\Mathematica\5.\AddOns\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows\CompilerAdditions\mldev32\include'
>     and also the file `ml32i1m.lib` in 
>     E:\math\Mathematica\5.\AddOns\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows\CompilerAdditions\mldev32\lib. Copy both files to a predetermined directory (we will refer to this directory as C:\xxx).
> - 2)  Copy the content of compressed file math.tar into C:\xxx.
> - 3)  Open Matlab command window and execute `mex –setup`. Choose “Microsoft Visual C/C++ version 6.0 in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio”.  This tells Matlab that it needs to use a C compiler (as opposed to Fortran compiler). You’ll need Microsoft Visual C/C++ installed. Do not choose the “Lcc C version 2.4 in C:\MATLAB6P1\sys\lcc” option.
>     4)    Open Matlab command window and run mathrun.m. This program will compile the C-file `math.c`.

The file I got shown as belew:

> [image]

Then I do step by step

(1) Find the `mathlink.h` and `ml32i1m.lib` in the following path

> D:\WolframResearch\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows\CompilerAdditions\mldev32\include
>   D:\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\8.0\SystemFiles\Links\MathLink\DeveloperKit\Windows\CompilerAdditions\mldev32\lib

(2)Copy the content of compressed file `math.zip` into C:\XXX

> [image]

(3) Compile in MATLAB

```
  mex -setup
```

> [image]
>   [image]

(4)last setp

```
addpath C:\XXX
run mathrun.m
```

> [image]

I don't know why?

---

**Update**

The matlab code in `mathrun.m`

```
addpath C:\XXX; 
% adds the directory C:\XXX to the list of directories which Matlab "sees" (referred to as paths)
mlpath='C:\XXX'   % The directory where mathlink.h is
mllib='C:\XXX\ml32i1m.lib'   % The library ml32i1m.lib

% make command
command=sprintf('mex -D__STDC __ -I % s % s % s', mlpath, 'math.c', mllib);
% compile
eval(command)
```

Comment: This toolbox appears to from 2004 and was written for what are now quite ancient versions of both Matlab and Mathematica. What `version` of Matlab do you have? And Mathematica?

Comment: @horchler - Judging from the last snapshot, it looks like it's R2012b.... but I don't think the OP has any chance in running the toolbox if it's from 2004.

Comment: @horchler, My MATLAB version is 2012b, inaddtion, *Mathematica *version is 8.0.4

Comment: The quotes around `caller` in the last line of the error look wrong to me. Is that the cause of the error? You have debug line by line and help yourself. Unless you can give a specific error source, I doubt if someone can be of help.

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar, Thks,please see my update:)

Comment: @ShutaoTang: Please let me know if you do get this to work somehow and any additional fixes you needed to apply. I'd be interested in trying it out. Thanks.

Comment: @horchler, it is my first to use matlab, so I failed.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the path is not correctly passed to `mex`, so it cannot find `math.c`. Comment the original line:

```
%command=sprintf('mex -D__STDC __ -I % s % s % s', mlpath, 'math.c', mllib);
```

and add this one instead:

```
command=sprintf('mex -D__STDC __ -I%s %s %s', mlpath, 'math.c', mllib);
```

because the `mex` documentation specifies that there should be no space between the `-I` switch and the input path. To be really on the safe side, you can even write:

```
command=sprintf('mex -D__STDC __ -I%s %s %s', mlpath, fullfile(mlpath,'math.c'), mllib);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution. However, `command=sprintf('mex -D__STDC __ -I%s %s %s', mlpath, 'math.c', mllib);` gives the warning information ` D:\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: '__' not found.` .In addtion, `command=sprintf('mex -D__STDC __ -I%s %s %s', mlpath, fullfile(mlpath,'math.c'), mllib);` also gives the ` D:\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: '__' not found.`